# How do you clear buffer result in Speech Recognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, speech-to-text, speech

I'm trying to write a speech recognizer that will have the ability to be cleared after some duration (like two seconds) without switching it off.

```swift
private func startRecording() throws {
    
    recognitionTask?.cancel()
    self.recognitionTask = nil
    
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .measurement, options: .duckOthers)
    try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode

    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else { fatalError("Unable to create a SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object") }
    recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true
    
    // Keep speech recognition data on device
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        recognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = false
    }
    
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in
        var isFinal = false
        
        if let result = result {
            self.textView.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString



            // MARK: here after 2 seconds my recognition should clear it's own result in string




            isFinal = result.isFinal
            print("Text \(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)")
        }
        
        if error != nil || isFinal {
            self.audioEngine.stop()
            inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

            self.recognitionRequest = nil
            self.recognitionTask = nil

            self.recordButton.isEnabled = true
            self.recordButton.setTitle("Start Recording", for: [])
        }
    }
    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    }
    
    audioEngine.prepare()
    try audioEngine.start()
    
    textView.text = "(Go ahead, I'm listening)"
}
```

I can not rebuild speech recognition. It should be working constantly.

I tried to do the following, but afterwards my microphone turns off:

```swift
inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
```